# C++11 Variadic Templates: 3..n int's separated into first, middle, last

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

As the title says I've got a Variadic Template that accepts at least 3 parameters (int's)

```
template<int p_first, int p_second, int p_third, int... p_rest>
```

and i need to split these into *first*, *middle* and *last*

```
class MyClass {
    OtherClass<p_first> first;
    // Works obviously

    // std::vector<OtherClass> middle... Doesn't work

    OtherClass<p_last> last;
    // No idea how to do this
}
```

Visual Studio 2015 C++ features are available

---

Edit: Sorry I forgot to mention key aspects.

- OtherClass implementation:

  ```
  template <int v>
  class OtherClass { ... };
  ```
- Yes, I want **all** the values *in the middle* (between *first* and *last*)
- ["the vector can't hold different types of OtherClass"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33171820/2607571) Thank you for reminding me of that. This might be the reason, that this isn't possible.
- ["Are you reinventing tuples?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171120/c11-variadic-templates-3-n-ints-seperated-into-first-middle-last#comment54150259_33171120) Maybe using tuples is really a better solution. Looking into it.

Thank you for the posts. I'll understand, test the code and comment soon!

Comment: so you need to determine the last and the middle value depending on how many integer parameters you get?

Comment: What're you doing with the middle values?

Comment: Are you reinventing [tuples](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)?

Comment: I also don't understand what you are wanting to do with the middle values. You can't have a `std::vector` of `OtherClass<I>...` as those are unrelated types.

Comment: You could have a `std::tuple`, however.

Comment: You you provide the full definition of OtherClass please?

Comment: @DenisBlank Why would we need that?   `template<int> class OtherClass {};` is enough to know, no?

Comment: It's also possible that he meant: `template<int...> class OtherClass {};` because it's still unknown what is the clear meaning of  `std::vector<OtherClass> middle...` which is the main aspect in this question.

Comment: @DenisBlank So we don't need the definition, just the declaration.

Comment: O i had to mention that it would be nice to see the declaration too to get more information about the background to improve the answers. It's still unknown what OtherClass is needed for.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention so much (see edit) but thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Boost.Hana](https://github.com/ldionne/hana) (requires a C++14 compiler):

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <tuple>
namespace hana = boost::hana;


template <int>
struct OtherClass { };

template <int ...I>
class MyClass {
    static constexpr auto ints = hana::tuple_c<int, I...>;

    OtherClass<hana::front(ints)> first;

    using Middle = typename decltype(
        hana::unpack(hana::slice_c<1, sizeof...(I) - 1>(ints), [](auto ...i) {
            return hana::type_c<std::tuple<OtherClass<ints[i]>...>>;
        })
    )::type;
    Middle middle;

    OtherClass<hana::back(ints)> last;
};

int main() {
    MyClass<0, 3, 2, 1> x;
}
```

Note that I'm abusing a Clang bug in the above, because lambdas are not allowed to appear in unevaluated contexts. To be standards-compliant, you should use a hand-written function object instead of the lambda when calling `hana::unpack`.

Also, if you go the Hana way, I would suggest that you use `hana::tuple` if compile-time performance is a consideration, since `std::tuple` is a slowpoke in all known standard library implementations.

Comment: Boost.Hana looks really interesting! (nice website and talk btw.) I got it to work with your code but `OtherClass<ints[i]>...>` needed to be changed to `OtherClass<i>...>`. I think you misunderstood my question there. Anyway, with this great library it seems to work flawlessly!

Comment: Thanks! And yes you're right about `OtherClass<ints[i]>` vs `OtherClass<i>`, I got confused. However, note that this solution will only work on Clang for the time being, because GCC still has C++14-related bugs and MSVC, ICC & al are still far behind in their C++14 support. So if MSVC support is a must, you should use something else.

Answer (score 8):

First, boilerplate.  I'm working in types, not constants, because metaprogramming with types is far easier.

```
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;

template<int I>using int_k=std::integral_constant<int, I>;

template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};

template<template<class...>class Z, class pack>
struct apply;
template<template<class...>class Z, class pack>
using apply_t=type_t<apply<Z,pack>>;
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct apply<Z, types<Ts...>>:tag<Z<Ts...>>{};
```

Now once we have a pack of middle elements, we can apply them.

```
template <std::size_t N, class... Ts>
using get_t = type_t< std::tuple_element< N, std::tuple<Ts...> > >;
```

gets the nth type from a list of types.

```
template <class Is, class pack>
struct get_slice;
template <class Is, class pack>
using get_slice_t=type_t<get_slice<Is,pack>>;
template<std::size_t...Is, class...Ts>
struct get_slice<std::index_sequence<Is...>,types<Ts...>>:
  types< get_t<Is, Ts...>... >{};
```

This lets us take a pack, and get a slice from it.

Offset an index sequence:

```
template<class Is, std::size_t I>
struct offset;
template<class Is, std::size_t I>
using offset_t=type_t<offset<Is,I>>;
template<std::size_t...Is, size_t I>
struct offset<std::index_sequence<Is...>, I>:
  tag<std::index_sequence<(I+Is)...>>
{};
```

Extract the middle elements starting at start of length len:

```
template<std::size_t start, std::size_t len, class pack>
struct get_mid:
  get_slice< offset_t< std::make_index_sequence<len>, start >, pack >
{};
template<std::size_t start, std::size_t len, class pack>
using get_mid_t=type_t<get_mid<start,len,pack>>;
```

and now we can split your elements into first, last and stuff the rest in a tuple:

```
template<int p_first, int p_second, int p_third, int...is>
class MyClass {
  using pack = types< int_k<p_first>, int_k<p_second>, int_k<p_third>, int_k<is>... >;
  OtherClass<p_first> first;

  using mid = get_mid_t<1, sizeof...(is)+1, pack >;

  template<class...Ts>
  using OtherClass_tuple = std::tuple<OtherClass<Ts::value>...>;

  apply_t< OtherClass_tuple, mid > middle;

  OtherClass<get_t<sizeof...(is)+2, pack>::value> last;
};
```

Comment: Out of interest, it seems like you have all of this useful boilerplate saved somewhere for easy access. Do you have a public repository of similar template stuff somewhere? Are other people free to use it for their own projects/answers?

Comment: @tart I just type it.  Each time I try to write it better.  The 200th time you write something, you have filed off rough edges, hopefully.

Comment: This is some very nice universal code! And seems like the answer to my problem... testing now

Answer (score 7):

You could write a helper struct to get the `N`th `int` from an `int` pack:

```
template <std::size_t N, int... I>
struct get_n : 
    std::integral_constant<int, 
        std::get<N>(std::array<int,sizeof...(I)> { I... })
    >
{};
```

Then you could write metafunctions to get the middle and end:

```
template <int... I>
using get_middle = get_n<sizeof...(I)/2 - 1, I...>;

template <int... I>
using get_end = get_n<sizeof...(I) - 1, I...>;
```

You can use this like so:

```
using p_last = get_end<p_third, p_rest...>;
OtherClass<p_last> last;
```

---

If you want a tuple of `OtherClass<N>` for all the middle elements, here's a fairly simple solution. See [Yakk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33171780/496161) for a more complex, flexible one.

```
template <template <int> class ToBuild, class Seq, int... Args>
struct build_tuple;

template <template <int> class ToBuild, std::size_t... Idx, int... Args>
struct build_tuple<ToBuild, std::index_sequence<Idx...>, Args...> {
    using type = std::tuple<ToBuild<get_n<Idx, Args...>::value>...>;   
};

template<int p_first, int p_second, int p_third, int... p_rest>
struct MyClass {
    MyClass() {
        typename build_tuple<OtherClass,
                            std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(p_rest) + 1>, 
                            p_second, p_third, p_rest...>::type middle;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the definition of OtherClass is unknown and the vector can't hold different types of OtherClass i assumed following code:

The code uses recursive template inheritance with integer_sequence to split the int pack.

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template<int...>
struct OtherClass { };

template<typename, int... >
struct Splitter;

template<int... middle, int next, int... rest>
struct Splitter<std::integer_sequence<int, middle...>, next, rest...>
    : Splitter<std::integer_sequence<int, middle..., next>, rest...> { };

template<int... middle, int last>
struct Splitter<std::integer_sequence<int, middle...>, last>
{
    static std::vector<int> const& get_vector()
    {
        static std::vector<int> const m = { middle... };
        return m;
    }

    using last_t = std::integral_constant<int,
        last
    >;
};

template<int p_first, int p_second, int p_third, int... p_rest>
class MyClass
{
    OtherClass<p_first> first;

    using splitter = Splitter<std::integer_sequence<int>, p_second, p_third, p_rest...>;

    std::vector<int> middle = splitter::get_vector();

    typename splitter::last_t last;
};
```

**[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a61e2227f703e065)**

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the template of OtherClass (see my edit). Although in my context this is unusable, this is the perfect solution for another problem I was having :D Thanks